# Random numbers exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm a beginner in Python. Could you help me solve this exercise?

Define a rolldies (n) function that simulates the roll of n dice and returns the ordered list of throws. (For example, rolldies (3) generates three random numbers between 1 and 6, e.g. 2, 5, 1, and returns the list [1, 2, 5].)

I made this, but it isn't what the exercise wants:

```
import random

def rolldies():
    die1 = random.randrange(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randrange(1, 6)
    die3 = random.randrange(1, 6)
    list=[]
    list.extend((die1, die2, die3))
    list.sort(reverse = False ) 
    return list

print(rolldies())
```

Comment: the trick is to realise that 3 is just one of the possible number of values that `n` can take. your function doesn't even take an `n` parameter right now!

Comment: Hint: let me put it a different way, if i asked you to write it for when n=1000, are you going to write the `random.randrange` 1000 times?

Comment: Hint: it should start `def roll_dice(n):`  since `n` is a parameter. (I can't bring myself to type the awful `rolldies` hopefully your professor won't insist on a misspelling). Use a `for` loop or an appropriate comprehension to populate the needed list.

Comment: You may want to check out loops https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops and functions https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions

Answer (score 2):

In your post, you say the function will be like `rolldies(n)`, so you need to define a parameter in your function. There are many ways to achieve the desired result.

> **Method 1:** a solution using *for loop*

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        number = random.randrange(1, 6)
        result.append(number)
    return sorted(result)


print(rolldies(3)) # display [3, 4, 5] for example
```

> **Method 2:** a solution using *list-comprehension*

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    return sorted([random.randrange(1, 6) for i in range(n)])


print(rolldies(3)) # display [2, 4, 5] for example
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a length of the list to your function name rolldies(). Try below code

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    list=[]
    for i in range(n):
        list.append(random.randrange(1, 6))
    list.sort(reverse = False ) 
    return list

print(rolldies(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` to loop `n` times and generate a random number. At each step you put the random number into the list.

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    roll_list = []  # This is the list where you store the rolls.
    for i in range(n):
        rand = random.randrange(1, 6)  # Generate a random number in each loop.
        print(rand)
        roll_list.append(rand)  # Add the random number to the list.
    roll_list.sort()  # Sort the list.
    return roll_list


# Here you call the function with a value for n
n = 3
print(rolldies(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop in order to make it a variable number of times and an empty list to store each roll of dice.

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    dice = [] #Empty list to store the rolls
    #For loop that runs n times
    for i in range(n):
        roll = random.randrange(1, 6)  #Roll the dice
        dice.append(roll)  #Store the roll in the list
    dice.sort(reverse = False)
    return dice

print(rolldies(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
list = []
for i in range(int(n)):
  list.append(random.randrange(1, 6))
list.sort() 
return list

print(rolldies(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way to do this is to use a function that's already provided: `random.choices` to return n numbers from population:

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    return sorted(random.choices(list(range(1,7)), k=n), reverse=False)

print(rolldies(10))
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you must use `randrange`, you can do this in a single list comprehension to make a list of `n` numbers with something like:

```
import random

def rolldies(n):
    return sorted([random.randrange(1, 7) for _ in range(n)], reverse = False)

print(rolldies(10))
# [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
```

Note: the range should be `(1,7)` if you want to include `6`.